# Use of header from a csv file in R

Tags: r

How can I access the header names from a .csv file in R?
When I import a .csv file in R that contains headers, I include `header = TRUE` in my code. Can I use the titles from the header afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the header names will be the names of the columns of the resulting `data.frame` and can be accessed by `colnames(df)`:

```
df <- read.csv("main.csv", header=TRUE)
cat(print(colnames(df))
```